# Bug when changing motion.div props on the fly

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am currently trying to build a component that takes in a `direction` prop like "left-to-right" or "right-to-left" and then once the content changes it should then animate in and out accordingly.

I have come this far...

`AnimationSwitch` component:

```js
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { FunctionComponent, PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

const MoveOffsetPx = 24;

const AnimationVariants = {
  'left-to-right': {
    initial: {
      opacity: 0,
      x: MoveOffsetPx,
    },
    animate: {
      opacity: 1,
      x: 0,
    },
    exit: {
      opacity: 0,
      x: -MoveOffsetPx,
    },
  },
  'right-to-left': {
    initial: {
      opacity: 0,
      x: -MoveOffsetPx,
    },
    animate: {
      opacity: 1,
      x: 0,
    },
    exit: {
      opacity: 0,
      x: MoveOffsetPx,
    },
  },
  'top-to-bottom': {
    initial: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: -MoveOffsetPx,
    },
    animate: {
      opacity: 1,
      y: 0,
    },
    exit: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: MoveOffsetPx,
    },
  },
  'bottom-to-top': {
    initial: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: MoveOffsetPx,
    },
    animate: {
      opacity: 1,
      y: 0,
    },
    exit: {
      opacity: 0,
      y: -MoveOffsetPx,
    },
  },
};

export type AnimateSwitchDirections = keyof typeof AnimationVariants;

type Props = PropsWithChildren<{
  uniqueKey: string;
  duration?: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | number;
  direction?: AnimateSwitchDirections;
  className?: string;
}>;

export const AnimateSwitch: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  children,
  uniqueKey,
  duration = 'md',
  direction = 'left-to-right',
  className,
}) => {
  return (
    <AnimatePresence initial={false} mode="wait">
      <motion.div
        className={className}
        key={uniqueKey}
        transition={{
          duration: 3,
          ease: 'easeInOut',
        }}
        {...AnimationVariants[direction]}
      >
        {children}
      </motion.div>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};
```

The problem arrives when I have a parent component and do the following...

Parent component:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [direction, setAnimationDirection] = useState('left-to-right')
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0)

   const onNext = useCallback(
    (options?: { back: boolean }) => {
      const currentIndex = OnboardingSteps.findIndex(s => s.id === step.id);

      if (options?.back) {
        setAnimationDirection('right-to-left');

        const previousStep = OnboardingSteps[currentIndex - 1];

        return setStep(previousStep);
      }

      const isLastStep = currentIndex === OnboardingSteps.length - 1;

      if (isLastStep) {
        return navigate('/');
      }

      setAnimationDirection('left-to-right');

      const nextStep = OnboardingSteps[currentIndex + 1];

      setStep(nextStep);
    },
    [navigate, step.id, setStep],
  );

  return (
    <AnimateSwitch direction={direction} uniqueKey={step}>
     {... content ...}
    </AnimateSwitch>
  )
}
```

It seems like the AnimationSwitch uses the `initial` animation state from the previous animation before using the correct one in the second part of the animation (`exit`).

How can I make the `motion.div` get the right props on the fly by changing the direction prop?

Basically, I want to call the animation direction (e.g. `setAnimationDirection('left-to-right')`) and then call the next step (e.g. `setStep((current) => current + 1)`) and the right animation should apply. I don't really know what I am doing wrong or if there is a better way to do this with framer-motion?

Comment: Have you tried framer motion's [Layout animations](https://www.framer.com/motion/layout-animations/)? With framer motion layout animations, "any layout change that happens as the result of a re-render will be animated."